# Animated layouts

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create a page where the layout change instead of loading a new page. The idea would be to have the user click on an item then rearrange all of the items on a page. I can figure out how to do this but what I can't figure out is how to create links for each page.

So if the user clicks on item A and gets layout A I would like to have a link for that.

If the user clicks on item B and gets layout B I would like to create a link for that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You could change a **class** on your HTML body. That would allow you to use different parts of your CSS depending on the layout. Each link could set the class using jQuery:

```
// In your javascript (within jQuery ready function)
$('#layoutTwoOne').click(function(event) {
    $('body').removeClass('layoutTwo').addClass('layoutOne');
});
$('#layoutTwoLink').click(function(event) {
    $('body').removeClass('layoutOne').addClass('layoutTwo');
});
```

In your HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="layoutOneLink">Switch to Layout One</a>
<a href="#" id="layoutTwoLink">Switch to Layout Two</a>
```

In your CSS:

```
body.layoutOne {
    background-color: black;
}
body.layoutTwo {
    background-color: white;
}
body.layoutOne div {
    /* Some special css for all divs in layout one */
}
```

The code could be more data-driven. It's a bit of a hack, but it will do what you need. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can essentially use any element you please as a link/button or whatever.

Jquery allows us to attach event listeners of sorts for events triggered by user interactions -

- mouse clicks
- double cicks
- keyboard key down/up
- etc...

These actions can be attached to any element you have in your HTML.  it could be -

- an `<a>` tag
- an `<img>` tag
- a `<td>` or `<tr>` in a table structure
- a generic `<div>` element
- etc...

You can bind a click even onto any element you please and have it trigger your `changeLayout()` function (or something similar).  The syntax for a simple (single) click handler looks like this -

```
$("#elementSelector").on('click',function(){
  // user has clicked the element!
  // do some cool animations and stuff!
});
```

That function will be triggered for any element with an `id` attribute equal to `elementSelector`.

Some examples of elements that fit the description -

- `<div id="elementSelector"></div>`
- `<a href="#" id="elementSelector"></a>`
- `<td id="elementSelector"></td>`